# Replacing one space with two spaces in Unix

Tags: shell

I am trying to replace every time there is one space with two spaces in Unix. We are just reading from standard input and writing to standard ouput. I also have to avoid using the functions awk and perl. For example if I read in something like `San Diego` it should print `San  Diego`. If there are already multiple spaces, it should just leave them alone.

Comment: `echo "this is a test" | sed s/' '/'  '/g`

Comment: Why the restriction of not using awk or perl?

Comment: Note: This has nothing to do with Unix. It's `bash` which is the relevant part here, and that behaves the same even if it's not on Unix (like e.g. on Linux).

Answer (score 1):

How about bash only? First test `file`:

```
$ cat file
 1
  2 3
    4  5
San Diego  NO
```

Then:

```
$ cat file | 
while IFS= read line
do 
  while [[ "$line" =~ (^|.+[^ ])\ ([^ ].*) ]]
  do 
    line="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}  ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
  done
  echo "$line"
done
  1
  2  3
    4  5
San  Diego  NO
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to a bit careful here not to forget spaces at the beginning or end.
I present three solutions for educational purpose:

```
sed 's/\(^\|[^ ]\) \($\|[^ ]\)/\1  \2/g'    # solution 1
sed 's/\( \+\)/ \1/g;s/ \(  \+\)/\1/g'      # solution 2
sed 's/ \( \+\)/\1/g;s/\( \+\)/ \1/g'       # solution 3
```

All three solutions make use of subexpressions:

> **[9.3.6 BREs Matching Multiple Characters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html)**
>
> A subexpression can be defined within a BRE by enclosing it between
>   the character pairs `\(` and `\)`. Such a subexpression shall match
>   whatever it would have matched without the `\(` and `\)`, except that
>   anchoring within subexpressions is optional behavior; see [BRE
>   Expression Anchoring](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_08). Subexpressions can be arbitrarily nested.
>
> The back-reference expression `'\n'` shall match the same (possibly
>   empty) string of characters as was matched by a subexpression enclosed
>   between "`\(`" and "`\)`" preceding the `'\n'`. The character `n` shall be a
>   digit from `1` through `9`, specifying the nth subexpression (the one that
>   begins with the nth `\(` from the beginning of the pattern and ends
>   with the corresponding paired `\)` ). The expression is invalid if
>   less than `n` subexpressions precede the `\n`. For example, the
>   expression "`.∗\1$`" matches a line consisting of two adjacent
>   appearances of the same string, and the expression `a*\1` fails to
>   match `a`. When the referenced subexpression matched more than one
>   string, the back-referenced expression shall refer to the last matched
>   string. If the subexpression referenced by the back-reference matches
>   more than one string because of an asterisk (`*`) or an interval
>   expression (see item (5)), the back-reference shall match the last
>   (rightmost) of these strings.

**Solution 1: `sed 's/\(^\|[^ ]\) \($\|[^ ]\)/\1  \2/g'`**

Here there are two subexpressions. The first subexpression `\(^\|[^ ]\)` matches the beginning of the line (`^`) or (`\|`) a non-space character (`[^ ]`). The second subexpression `\($\|[^ ]\)` is similar but with the end-of-line (`$`).

**Solution 2: `sed 's/\( \+\)/ \1/g;s/ \(  \+\)/\1/g'`**

This replaces one-or more spaces by the same amount of spaces and an extra one. Afterwards we correct the ones with 3 spaces or more by removing a single space from those.

**Solution 3: `sed 's/ \( \+\)/\1/g;s/\( \+\)/ \1/g'`**

This does the same thing as solution 2 but inverts the logic. First remove a space from all sequences that have more then one space, and afterwards add a space. This one-liner is just one-character shorter then solution 2.

**Example:** based on solution 1

The following commands are nothing more then `echo "string" | sed ...`, but to show the spaces, wrapped into a `printf` statement.

```
# default string
$ printf "|%s|" " foo bar  car "
| foo bar  car |
# spaces replaced
$ printf "|%s|" "$(echo " foo bar  car " | sed 's/\(^\|[^ ]\) \($\|[^ ]\)/\1  \2/g')"
|  foo  bar  car  |
# 3 spaces in front and back
$ printf "|%s|" "$(echo "   foo bar  car   " | sed 's/\(^\|[^ ]\) \($\|[^ ]\)/\1  \2/g')"
|   foo  bar  car   |
```

**note:** If you want to replace any form of blanks (spaces and tabs in any encoding) by the same doubled blank, you could use :

```
sed 's/\(^\|[^[:blank:]]\)\([[:blank:]]\)\($\|[^[:blank:]]\)/\1\2\2\3/g'
sed 's/\(^\|[[:graph:]]\)\([[:blank:]]\)\($\|[[:graph:]]\)/\1\2\2\3/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```
cat input.txt | sed 's,\([[:alnum:]]\) \([[:alnum:]]\),\1  \2,'
```

should work for that purpose.

Comment: nice, but... I think that you forgotten to cover a `single white space`

Answer (score 0):

### replace only occurrence of 1 space between 2 chars hat are not white space  with 2 spaces

```
  `sed 's/\([^ ]\) \([^ ]\)/\1  \2/g' file`
```

`1)` `[^ ]` - not space char

`2)` `\1  \2` - first expression found in Parenthesis, 2 spaces, second Parentheses expiration

`3)` sed used with `s///g` is replacing the regex in the first `//` with the value in the second `//`